# No output out of llvm-objdump for rustc compiled RISC-V32IM binary

Tags: assembly, rust, riscv

When I compile following rust code:

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_panic: &PanicInfo<'_>) -> ! {
    loop {}
}

fn mult(a: u32, b: u32) -> u32 {
    return a * b;
}

#[no_mangle]
fn main() -> u32 {
    return mult(3, 4);
}
```

via command

```
rustc --target riscv32i-unknown-none-elf -Ctarget-feature=+m -O simple.rs
```

and then run

```
llvm-objdump -d simple
```

I get following output without any instructions:

```
simple: file format ELF32-riscv
```

But when I do

```
rustc --target riscv32i-unknown-none-elf -Ctarget-feature=+m -O --emit asm simple.rs
```

and look into resulting `simple.s` file I see:

```
        .text
        .attribute      4, 16
        .attribute      5, "rv32i2p0_m2p0"
        .file   "simple.5d8cddf570d1dcfb-cgu.0"
        .section        .text.rust_begin_unwind,"ax",@progbits
        .hidden rust_begin_unwind
        .globl  rust_begin_unwind
        .p2align        2
        .type   rust_begin_unwind,@function
rust_begin_unwind:
.LBB0_1:
        j       .LBB0_1
.Lfunc_end0:
        .size   rust_begin_unwind, .Lfunc_end0-rust_begin_unwind

        .section        .text.main,"ax",@progbits
        .globl  main
        .p2align        2
        .type   main,@function
main:
        li      a0, 12
        ret
.Lfunc_end1:
        .size   main, .Lfunc_end1-main

        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

I have tried installing [RISC-V GNU Toolchain](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain) and compiling similar C programs, then running `llvm-objdump` and this way I got output with instructions as expected.

I have also tried to find in the binary these instructions present in `simple.s` via their opcodes programmatically and to no avail.

What am I doing wrong? Why does disassembly differ from `simple.s`? How do I get rustc to compile a binary with actual instructions?

Comment: Does `llvm-objdump -D simple` show anything?  I expect it would disassemble the `.text.main` and `.text.rust_begin_unwind` sections, not *just* `.text`, but maybe not.  `-D` disassembles all sections (including definitely-not-code sections like `.data`)

Comment: @PeterCordes, there are no sections `.text.*` in the output
https://pastebin.com/9BSAjSEv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default linker script likely uses the symbol `_start` as the program entry point, not `main`. (I have not been able to verify this on a RISC-V target.) Legacy linker behavior if the `_start` symbol is missing is to use the lowest text address instead (which is determined by section placement even if there is no code). Rust links with `--gc-sections`, so the final binary does not contain your `main` code even it is included in the assembly.

If I rename `main` to `_start`, I get some machine code in the output binary, but of course this is unlikely to work because the required initialization is missing.

The Rust RISC-V team suggests using the [`riscv-rt` crate](https://crates.io/crates/riscv-rt) and the [`[#entry]` macro](https://docs.rs/riscv-rt/0.11.0/riscv_rt/attr.entry.html).